# ¿Como realizar peticiones asincronas en angular 13?

Tags: angular

Estoy construyendo una app de ventas en angular 13, el problema que presento es que estoy realizando peticiones a mi Backend para obtener ciertos datos el tema en cuestión es que estos datos no se resuelven en orden pues hay ocasiones en las que alguna de esas peticiones tarda más en resolverse y necesito esos datos para ejecutar algunos procesos..

este es mi ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
    this.getCategory(this.company.compId);
    this.getTaxe(this.company.compId);
    this.getPresentation(this.company.compId);
    this.getAccountGroup();
    this.getWarehouseforCompany(this.company.compId)

    this.idRouter = this.activateRouter.snapshot.params['id']
    if (this.idRouter) this.getArticle(this.idRouter)        
  }
```

como ven cuando tengo un id en la URL llama al artículo para pintar los datos en el componente de edición entonces en artículos tengo una función que recorre un array de Taxes que se cargan con this.getTaxe(this.company.compId); hay ocasiones en que getTaxe ya tiene los datos pero hay otras en las que esta llamada tarda en resolverse pues el Back no le ha mandado los datos aun y obtengo que cuando se llamó al getArticle aun Taxe estaba vacío.
por eso quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder lanzar estas peticiones en orden para que continúe con la siguiente cuando se resuelva la anterior...

(Nota: esto puede pasar con cualquiera de las llamadas al backend que están en el ngOnInit lo quedeseo es poder controlar el orden de las llamadas para asegurar la buena carga del componente o poder mostrar el componente luego que ya todas las peticiones esten resueltas ese seria otro punto que quisiera manejar)

Es mi primer vez preguntando algo espero me haya sabido explicar y no pase vergüenza por no saber redactar la pregunta...
de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si una consulta depende de otra anterior lo que debes hacer es esperar a que termine la anterior. Para esto debes utilizar el operador `await` y para poder utilizar este operador, el método debe ser asíncrono con su palabra reservada `async`, por ejemplo:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    ....
    await this.getTaxe(this.company.compId);
    ....
}
```

Se debe tomar en cuenta que el método `getTaxe` sea una promesa.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy trabajando con httpClient de Angular, he leido sobre el uso de switchMap trate de hacerlo con forkJoin pero las peticiones se hacen en paralelo, entonces leia algo sobre switchMap pero estoy confundido